# Bodybuilding diet for south indian

Tags: diet

I am from southern part of india. There is no comprehensive diet plan exclusive for south indian where rice is the major staple food

Comment: Can you be a bit descriptive about your goal? Like what you want to do? We don't know what your diet looks like, apart from rice which is mainly carb, with other macros and some micros in traces. Please let us know your goal, and regarding diet, you need to eat enough protein like around 1 gram per body weight in lbs, to build mass along with carbs, fat and other micro-nutrients.

Answer (score 1):

I am a south Indian myself, and I understand your difficulty. Are you a vegetarian? If you are, soy is a major source of protein. It's also called as mealmaker, and it is available in most places. Also, sprouts and groundnuts are very good sources of proteins. If you are really serious about bodybuilding, then there are vegetarian protein supplements available online. But be careful, buy only from reputed vendors. If you are a non-vegetarian, eggs, chicken and milk should be your staple food.